# Is there a way to write on my iPad and my friend's iPad with one screen?

Tags: ipad

Suppose that two persons A and B have iPad respectively.

They want to use some note app such as Notability or Goodnotes, and
share their screen.

It means that if A writes something on A's iPad, then B can see it on B's iPad at the same time, and vise versa.

Is it possible? If it is possible, please let me know the way.

And if it is possible, I want to find the way that the writing quality is best.

Comment: Have you thought of an app like [Google Docs](https://apps.apple.com/en-gb/app/google-docs/id842842640)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two tools that I have used to do near-instaneous collaboration on iPads:

- [Freeform](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2022/12/apple-launches-freeform-a-powerful-new-app-designed-for-creative-collaboration/).  (Free).  This requires a a device running iPadOS/iOS 16.2 or later.  Canvases can be shared via messaging or through Facetime.
- [OneNote](https://products.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-notebooks-in-microsoft-onenote-7403c62f-9dbc-4393-8258-36d78ae5ba11).  (Free) I have used this in two scenarios, while taking notes on a Mac and using the iPad version of OneNote to be a drawing tablet.  I was able to compose my notes and annotate with the iPad in close to real-time (only a second or so lag).  The second was with colleagues in three different cities.  We were all able to draw, annotate and add documents to a shared notebook live.  I had this capability since iOS 14 (possibly earlier).

There are other whiteboard/canvas sharing apps available.  Some are built into the meeting/collaboration application themselves:

- [Microsoft Whiteboard](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-whiteboard/id1352499399)
- [MS Teams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/compare-microsoft-teams-options-b?ef_id=_k_ca564448e43b1fcc457920c15a8df977_k_&OCID=AIDcmmkq3fcu5u_SEM__k_ca564448e43b1fcc457920c15a8df977_k_&msclkid=ca564448e43b1fcc457920c15a8df977)
- [Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/12570780371341-Sharing-a-whiteboard)

(I’ve used both Teams and Zoom, but not had the opportunity to use a collaborative whiteboard as of yet.  Same goes for MS Whiteboard; I have it, it works great, but I haven’t used it for collaboration yet).

It’s worth mentioning that iPadOS 17 is slated to have a [Live Collaboration feature](https://techcrunch.com/2023/06/05/ipad-os-17s-live-collaboration-on-pdfs-could-challenge-google-docs/).